# UIcollectioncell with UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout does not apply height and width after adding constraint

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I tried to put three items in a row with UICollectionView

```
extension DemoController : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    //1
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        //2
        let paddingSpace = sectionInsets.left  * (itemsPerRow + 1)
        let availableWidth = view.frame.width - paddingSpace
        let widthPerItem = availableWidth / itemsPerRow
        
        return CGSize(width: widthPerItem, height: widthPerItem)
    }
    
    //3
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return sectionInsets
    }
    
    // 4
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return sectionInsets.left
    }
}
```

It works okay if the cell is empty or if I put a view inside and only add constraint at the top or left like [image]
and I get output like
[image]

However, if I add constraint at right and bottom, the height and width of the cell do not work anymore.[image] [image]

where am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Collection view fix]

As you can see from my attached image, you must turn the Estimated Size of the collection view to ***None*** so that the collection view calculates your size based on the Collection View FlowLayout that you defined, otherwise it will calculate the size of the collection view based on your UILabel's size.

Answer (score 0):

The `UILabel` has auto-resizing property, ie., it takes the size of its contents. So, if you're trying to provide constraints to all four sides it's better to provide the relation between the constraints to `greaterThanOrEqualTo` for `leading` and `top` and `lessThanOrEqualTo` for `trailing` and `bottom` in the constraint property on the storyboard. Here an example:

[image: Constraint properties]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Definitely it's not related to my question but still I tried your solution and it does not work.